# PHP how to pass a variable from another page to a page that has a validation form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to pass a variable from another page to a page that has a validation form

Page1.php is the page contains the variable I want to pass. Let's say page2.php?var=$var
Page2.php is the page that has a validation form I want to store this variable from page1.php.
Let's say $var = $_REQUEST['var'];

The form of page2.php kind like this:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  } 
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
    
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
      }
      
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
      }
    
     
    }
    
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    ?>
    
    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
    
    <?php
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $email;
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I pass the variable from page1.php to page2.php, first time is ok.
But as long as I hit "submit", the passed variable will be lost.
How could I keep this variable after multiple times of "submit"? so I can insert this variable along with the form to database

Comment: Set a session variable.

Comment: Or put the value into a hidden field, so that it submit together with the rest of the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

to validate the data in different files you just need to require the folder that accepts the form contents to the validation file